# notepad++ 7.9 python script print stopped working

Tags: python, notepad++

I have a script that has worked for a long time in notepad++ using the python plugin.
I am on Windows 10.
It just inserts a template with time information at the current file position.
I use it weekly.
I put some debug in it to make sure the data was there and the script was executing and they are.
Did print change? it now does absolutely nothing visibly except print out my temporary message boxes.
I would appreciate an answer, pointer, or debug hint.
thanks

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

basicFormat = '%Y%m%d'
extendedFormat = basicFormat + " " + "%A"

dt2 = datetime.strptime(time.strftime( basicFormat ),basicFormat)

start2 = dt2 - timedelta(days = (dt2.weekday() + 1) % 7)

#print(start2.strftime( basicFormat + " " + "%A" ))
theDays = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

for incr in theDays:
    print('')
    print('')
    print('-------------------------')
    print("-------------------------")
    notepad.messageBox("SCHEDULETIME4.PY IN LOOP INCR =", str(((start2+timedelta(days=incr)).strftime( extendedFormat ))), 0)
    print((start2+timedelta(days=incr)).strftime( extendedFormat ))
```

it used to print out something like this:

---

---

20201101 Sunday

---

---

20201102 Monday

---

---

20201103 Tuesday

---

---

20201104 Wednesday

---

---

20201105 thursday

---

---

20201106 Friday

---

---

20201107 Saturday

Comment: `NameError: name 'notepad' is not defined` is the error. What is `notepad` variable and where is it?

Comment: This script for itself works fine. So you should check if something on the notepad++ or python plugin side has changed.

Comment: well python is evidently implemented using scintilla in notepad++. 'notepad' points to the notepad++ editor from where the scripts are invoked. Does that make sense?

Comment: I just did an update and it stopped working. I tried installing older versions and still can't get things to work though the 'sample' scripts are working evidently. Is there some specific place I can/should be reviewing errors?

Comment: Does Notepad++ run a certain install of Python that possibly got broken i.e. is it embedded in the plugin or is it using some Python outside of notepad++ that I could try adjusting? Once again everything is working except the print statement..